# MongoDB _id returns undefined on frontend (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I created a simple fullstack webapp using NodeJS & Express + MongoDB to build the backend API and Vue.JS for the frontend.

All the Write Read and Delete API worked perfectly (I tested it using Postman). Everything works perfectly as well on the frontend, except when I tried to iterate (v-for) on an array of objects to get the _id, it doesn't work.

The array called posts has the attributes of 'text' and 'createdAt'. The v-for works perfectly and output the 2 attributes as expected. However, I tried to output _id (default id from MongoDB) but it returned "undefined".

This causes a problem because if I can't get _id, it wouldn't be possible for me to delete a specific post using the existing backend delete API.

From my understanding, in the backend side, the _id needs to be converted into ObjectId first before it can be used for db querying. But on the frontend (vue) I am not sure on how can turn _id into ObjectId. Am I getting into the right direction here?

```
 <div class="post" v-for="(post,i) in posts " :key="post._id" :index="i" :item="post" @dblclick="deletePost(post._id)">
        {{post.createdAt.getDate()}}/{{post.createdAt.getMonth() + 1}}/{{post.createdAt.getFullYear()}}
        <p class="text">{{post.text}}</p>
      </div>
...
```

```
methods: {
    async deletePost(id){
      console.log(id) //this returns undefined
      await PostService.deletePost(id);
      this.posts = await PostService.getPosts();
    }
  },  
...
```

```
//del post in PostService.js
    static deletePost(id){
        return axios.delete(url+id)
    }
```

```
//backend delete api

router.delete('/:id',async (req,res)=>{
    const posts = await loadPostCollection()
    console.log(ObjectID(req.params.id))
    await posts.deleteOne({_id: ObjectID(req.params.id)});
    res.status(200).send()
})
```

expected output: _id of each 'post', e.g:5cfa8c29f74c65ae485a6d93
actual output: undefined

no error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the property reference `post`, like this:

```
<div class="post" v-for="(post,i) in posts " :key="post._id" :post="post" @dblclick="deletePost(post._id)">
        {{post.createdAt.getDate()}}/{{post.createdAt.getMonth() + 1}}/{{post.createdAt.getFullYear()}}
        <p class="text">{{post.text}}</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I had? I had post._id on @dblclick. Could you please elaborate more on your answer? Thanks.

Comment: It's not exactly what you had. Notice in my answer there is a `:post="post"` directive.

Comment: Can you post the full structure of what the response is returning?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to convert **_id** to Mongo ObjectID on the FrontEND.

Your code looks normal, send all post object to function like that and debug it.

> @dblclick="deletePost(post)"

Probably your backend return **_id** as an **object**.

Comment: I tried to console.log the post object, but it only returned a bunch of getters and setters for the 2 attributes (createdAt and text). :/ I couldn't find anything regarding _id

Comment: You should check backend code. Because there is not any _id field.